# RIA Services error but not used

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, wcf-ria-services, asp.net-webpages

I created an ASP.NET MVC WebPages application. Works perfectly local. Works perfectly on the server when I install it as a website. However when it is installed as an IIS application (level below another website, using the same application pool) all it does is throwing this exception:

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Apparently something related to WCF RIA services, which is not used. All I use is Linq to SQL. How is this possible?

Server: Windows Server 2008 R2 with IIS 7.5

Comment: I found that part of the web.config was inherited from the parent website which did use OData (RIA services). The thing is I don't find how I can disable this at the "child" website. I still had to copy 2 assemblies to the child bin folder...

Answer (score 2):

Check the web.config of your application if it contains an entry like:

```
<httpModules>
  <add name="DomainServiceModule"
       type="System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.DomainServiceHttpModule, System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
</httpModules>
```

It is located in the `<system.web>` section.

Theres is also another entry like:

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
  <add name="DomainServiceModule" 
       preCondition="managedHandler"
       type="System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.DomainServiceHttpModule, System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
</modules>
```

in the `<system.webserver>` section.

Remove the entries, then you should not get the exception.

Comment: I tried that (in the modules section - running in Integrated mode) but didn't work.

Comment: Do you also removed the entry in <system.webserver>? I´ve updated my answer

Comment: Actually I've tried both but still it required the 2 assemblies (Hosting and Server) to be deployed in the bin folder. Isn't there a way in IIS to tell the sub-application to not inherit anything from the parent level and act like it's a completely separate application?

Comment: @Koen Maybe you need to deactivate `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests` in your main site. If it is enabled.

Comment: Similarly, in the IIS GUI I dclicked the Modules icon for my site and removed it from there.

Answer (score 0):

I know it too late, but may be my answer will be useful for some people.
I had similar problem, but no corresponded to IIS.

So, I had web app based on RIA services. This app used separate dll (DAL) which contained some classes attributed by RIA attributes (of course, it had reference to RIA dll). The dll (DAL) was referenced by another app which did not use RIA and raised same error as you mentioned (but only with `System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Server`).
This error was raised only during WCF channel creation (ChannelFactory<>). So I suppose WCF should know about all referenced dlls during analyzing of attributes of contract's classes. But I did not found any explanation why WCF don't used only own attributes whithout analizing all of them.